# How to escape Illegal Character '|'

Tags: android, json, url, illegalargumentexception, illegal-characters

`Url` which I am using to parse a document read using `Json` is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/150205375156742/feed?access_token=520625188052604|GsCYVGBJKs5N_O1AX9XrrsulrWc
```

which is throwing `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
04-19 23:08:02.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17068): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 76: https://graph.facebook.com/150205375156742/feed?access_token=520625188052604|GsCYVGBJKs5N_O1AX9XrrsulrWc
```

when I am trying to encode the url using `urlEncoder.encode()` it is causing another exception:

```
04-20 11:43:16.280: W/System.err(31984): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "graph.facebook.com": No address associated with hostname
```

Comment: Use `URLEncoder.encode("urString", "UTF-8");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I am trying to encode the url

Don't URL encode the whole URL. Just encode the parts, for example the value part of `access_token`. That should turn the `|` to `%7c`.

Comment: yeah,I tried same but still it is resulting in UnknownHostException

Comment: That's a different issue. Is the device/emulator you're running the code on connected to the internet?

Comment: yes my device is connected to Internet.Strange thing here is that the same URL without any edits is giving desired output on one of the devices but throwing runtime exception while testing code on other devices

Comment: I was using %7C instead of %7c .Now my code is working.Thanx a lot.

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference betweren `%7c` and `%7C`. The problem was likely somewhere else.